# Date Picker in java script

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, datepicker

I am creating dynamics web project with jsp, in that i need to use date picker using only java script(not j query), I need to use only Tab and arrow button to navigate date to date and enter button of keyboard to select date from calendar, and it also allow me select date using Mouse also.
     Now i am using Date picker of java script its working with mouse but its not working with Tab,arrow.Enter key from keyboard
    if any one has any idea please let me know

Comment: it will be helpful if you can provide a sample with jsfiddle and let us tweak with the code :D

Comment: The answer may be very different depending on how you've implemented it, e.g. as a series of select elements, or a small calendar grid.

Comment: You can see my code in this link http://jsfiddle.net/KutUv/